# error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file (@types/jasmine)

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I am receiving the following error when attempting to build my project (using Angular CLI)

```
ERROR in ../my-app/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(18,1): error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: Expected, SpyObjMethodNames, clock, CustomEqualityTester, CustomMatcherFactory, ExpectationFailed, SpecFunction, SpyObj, jasmine
```

I am using VSCode, and when I go to the line in question, I have the option to view the file it says its conflicting with.

This takes me to a file at the following location:

`/Users/<user_name>/Library/Caches/typescript/3.3/node_modules/@types/jasmine/ts3.1/index.d.ts`

I'm a little lost to understand why the TS compiler is trying to use this cached type definition, what could be going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing node_modules and package-lock.json, clearing npm cache (npm cache clean --force) and reinstalling dependencies?

Comment: will you please share your typescript version

Comment: Thanks @TheParam - I tried the steps you suggested but I still get the same errors. I just checked the version of TypeScript the angular CLI is using when it does the build and its on 3.2.4, I see that caches path I shared above is referencing a 3.3 version of TS, so perhaps this is what the problem is, the version difference between cached copy and the one in my node_modules folder in my project?

Comment: yes that might be the issue. you can delete the cached  folder and reinstall the typescript would help

Comment: You solve this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Which framework are you using to test your application?

Answer (score 5):

Just answered the same question here: [Definitions of identifiers conflict with those in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57418017/definitions-of-identifiers-conflict-with-those-in-another-file/59090895#59090895)

Posting it again.

---

Check `types` subsection in your `tsconfig.spec.json`, most probably it has something like that

```
"types": [
  "jasmine",
  "node"
]
```

I removed `jasmine` so my `types` section looks like that:

```
"types": [
  "node"
]
```

and it helped.

Answer (score 4):

Having had the same problems when migrating from Angular 6.x to 8.x (typescript 3.5+) with both @types/jasmine type-files (index.d.ts & 3.1/index.d.ts) competing with each other i solved it the following way:

## Quick overview

1. Removed @types/jasmine from package.json and instead added its 3.1/index.d.ts as a static file within my sourcecode.
2. As @types/jasminewd2 references @types/jasmine, also removed this lib from package.json and added as static file.
3. Changed some config-files to recognize the static-type-files.
4. Re-install libs

## Steps in detail

**1. Removed:**

entries from package.json

```
   "devDependencies": {
       ...
       "@types/jasmine": "3.4.0",
       "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.6",
       ...
   }
```

**2. Added instead:**

folders & files to file-structure below src-folder

```
src (folder)
   ...
   @types
      jasmine
         index.d.ts (from node_modules/@types/jasmine/3.1/index.d.ts)
      jasminewd2
         index.d.ts (from node_modules/@types/jasminewd2/index.d.ts)
```

**3. Changed configs:**

tsconfig.json (where XXX corresponds to your folder-structure)

```
   ...
   "typeRoots": [
      ...
      "src/ XXX /@types"
   ]
   ...
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
   ...
   "types": [
      ...
      "jasminewd2"
   ]
   ...
```

**4. Re-install libs**

run `npm install`

## Once conflicts will be resumed lateron

- undo the above steps
- re-install packages with

`npm install @types/jasmine --save-dev`

`npm install @types/jasminewd2 --save-dev`

## Additional background

As searching the internet showed only 2 similar complaints the assumption is close, that the above mentioned solution is a fix only, but there must be a better one (otherwise more people would complain about the problem). it might be that there is an unrecognized error somewhere within the configuration of the angular-project that could lead to a point where a decision between "we're using typescript below 3.1" and "we're using typescript from 3.1 up" isn't possible within @types/jasmine.

- [error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file (@types/jasmine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259962/error-ts6200-definitions-of-the-following-identifiers-conflict-with-those-in-an)
- [Definitions of identifiers conflict with those in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57418017/definitions-of-identifiers-conflict-with-those-in-another-file)

Answer (score 2):

I had to add [skipLibCheck](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck) to my `tsconfig.json` file.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    // ...
  }
}
```

### Warning

As [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck) says,

> A common case where you might think to use skipLibCheck is when there are **two copies of a library’s types in your node_modules**. In these cases, you should consider using a feature like [yarn's resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) to **ensure there is only one copy of that dependency in your tree** or investigate how to ensure there is only one copy by understanding the dependency resolution to fix the issue without additional tooling.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is getting this error while using mangoose, types are included in mongoose by default for 5.11 so just remove the `@types/mongoose` from your devDependencies and it will work fine. Refer to this. 
[@types/mongoose - Type Definitions conflict with those in mongoose 5.11
#49950](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/49950)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had typescript installed globally.

Run `npm ls -g --depth 0` to see if you have it installed globally.

Run `npm uninstall -g typescript` to remove.