# Definitions of identifiers conflict with those in another file

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I'm updating an old component from Typescript 6 to 8. I've updated the Jasmine dependencies in the `package.json`, but now I'm getting an error:

> "Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file:
>
> ImplementationCallback, ExpectedRecursive, Expected,
>   SpyObjMethodNames, CustomEqualityTester, CustomMatcherFactory,
>   ExpectationFailed, SpecFunction, SpyObj, jasmine".

The two conflicting files are the following:

```
@types/jasmine/index.d.ts

@types/jasmine/ts3.1/index.d.ts
```

I've already tried deleting the cache as well as deleting node_modules and package-lock then reinstalling everything. I've tried deleting either file and using the other as the only index.d.ts file, but then I get the error "Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'."

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: i just answered that question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259962/error-ts6200-definitions-of-the-following-identifiers-conflict-with-those-in-an/57592510#57592510

Answer (score 12):

I'm actually migrating an angular 6 app to angular 8 and have encounter the same problem as described here. I have found an alternative solution that works for me.

Adding this flag to tsconfig.json did the trick for me:

"skipLibCheck": true

The documentation reads "Skip type checking of all declaration files (*.d.ts)." Not happy with it at all, but it works while I finish the migration of all code related things.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank's mate, it really saves my day!

Answer (score 1):

Just answered the same question here: [error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file (@types/jasmine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259962/error-ts6200-definitions-of-the-following-identifiers-conflict-with-those-in-an/57592510#57592510)

Posting it again. If that's wrong, please edit/advice how to do properly

---

Having had the same problems when migrating from Angular 6.x to 8.x (typescript 3.5+) with both @types/jasmine type-files (index.d.ts & 3.1/index.d.ts) competing with each other i solved it the following way:

## Quick overview

1. Removed @types/jasmine from package.json and instead added its 3.1/index.d.ts as a static file within my sourcecode.
2. As @types/jasminewd2 references @types/jasmine, also removed this lib from package.json and added as static file.
3. Changed some config-files to recognize the static-type-files.
4. Re-install libs

## Steps in detail

**1. Removed:**

entries from package.json

```
   "devDependencies": {
       ...
       "@types/jasmine": "3.4.0",
       "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.6",
       ...
   }
```

**2. Added instead:**

folders & files to file-structure below src-folder

```
src (folder)
   ...
   @types
      jasmine
         index.d.ts (from node_modules/@types/jasmine/3.1/index.d.ts)
      jasminewd2
         index.d.ts (from node_modules/@types/jasminewd2/index.d.ts)
```

**3. Changed configs:**

tsconfig.json (where XXX corresponds to your folder-structure)

```
   ...
   "typeRoots": [
      ...
      "src/ XXX /@types"
   ]
   ...
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
   ...
   "types": [
      ...
      "jasminewd2"
   ]
   ...
```

**4. Re-install libs**

run `npm install`

## Once conflicts will be resumed lateron

- undo the above steps
- re-install packages with

`npm install @types/jasmine --save-dev`

`npm install @types/jasminewd2 --save-dev`

## Additional background

As searching the internet showed only 2 similar complaints the assumption is close, that the above mentioned solution is a fix only, but there must be a better one (otherwise more people would complain about the problem). it might be that there is an unrecognized error somewhere within the configuration of the angular-project that could lead to a point where a decision between "we're using typescript below 3.1" and "we're using typescript from 3.1 up" isn't possible within @types/jasmine.

- [error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file (@types/jasmine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259962/error-ts6200-definitions-of-the-following-identifiers-conflict-with-those-in-an)
- [Definitions of identifiers conflict with those in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57418017/definitions-of-identifiers-conflict-with-those-in-another-file)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've tried this solution twice, and neither time yielded the result I was looking for; I'm still getting that same error. Thanks for trying, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check `types` subsection in your `tsconfig.spec.json`, most probably it has something like that

```
"types": [
  "jasmine",
  "node"
]
```

I removed `jasmine` so my `types` section looks like that:

```
"types": [
  "node"
]
```

and it helped.