# error TS6200 error: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting this error in my project. Please help :(

node_modules/mongoose/index.d.ts:1:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: NativeDate, NativeError, Mongoose, SchemaTypes, STATES, connection, mongo, version, CastError, Collection, Connection, Error, QueryCursor, VirtualType, Schema, SchemaDefinition, Subdocument, Array, DocumentArray, Buffer, ObjectId, Decimal128, Query, mquery, Aggregate, SchemaType, Promise, PromiseProvider, Model

1 declare module 'mongoose' {

node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts:80:1
80 declare module "mongoose" {
~~~~~~~

Conflicts are in this file.
node_modules/mongoose/index.d.ts:1143:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate index signature for type 'string'.

1143     [k: string]: string;

```
// package.json

{
  "name": "whatsapp-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Whatsapp Bot",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc && node build/index.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=dev nodemon -e ts --exec \"npm run compile\"",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=prod node build/index.js",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/m3rashid/whatsapp-bot.git",
  "author": "MD Rashid Hussain <mdrashid.hussain.786.01@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mongoose-auto-increment": "^5.0.34",
    "@types/node": "16",
    "@types/pdfkit": "^0.12.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.9.1",
    "eslint": "^8.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^11.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.6",
    "mongoose-auto-increment": "^5.0.1",
    "pdfkit": "^0.13.0",
    "venom-bot": "^4.0.4"
  }
}
```

```
// how i am making schemas/models

import mongoose from "mongoose";

interface LinkDocument extends mongoose.Document {
  url: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  imageUrl: string;
}

const linkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  url: String,
  title: String,
  description: String,
  imageUrl: String,
});

const Link = mongoose.model<LinkDocument>("Link", linkSchema);
export default Link;
```

I thought of adding `"skipLibCheck": true` to my `tsconfig.json` but then I get other errors `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')` in the venom.create() function

Also, this way, I lose strict type checks, what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to occur when using Yarn 2 or Yarn 3 (Yarn "Berry") and workspaces. Yarn creates hardlinks for the workspaces, and TS is unable to correctly deal with this.

See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14565#issuecomment-1014112024 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36294 for more details.

---

**Old post:**

Are you by any chance using the new Visual Studio 2022 `.esproj` project type? We just migrated from VS2019 to VS2022 and from a `.njsproj` to an `.esproj` and these errors started appearing.

(Sorry, I'd comment, but I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67454333/14239942

Comment: no, I am using vscode

Comment: I think I figured out the root cause of this! See my comment at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14565#issuecomment-1014112024 

Comment: It looks like this has been fixed in Visual Studio 17.2 